# Error collect2 : ld returned exit status

Tags: c

When I try to compile my file, I have this error:

```
/tmp/ccN3Rs5C.o : Dans la fonction « BellmanFord » :
bellman.c:(.text+0x27c) : référence indéfinie vers « min »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I searched on several forums without success.

The problem is my function?

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: `ld` is the linker.  It seems to be complaining that your code is calling a function named `min` for which no definition is available.  If you've not written a `min()` function or macro then that's quite natural.  If you have written a `min()` function then you must include the object file containing that function in the link.  If you have written a `min()` macro then you'll need to `#include` the file containing it into `bellman.c`.

Comment: In future: please use `export LANG=C` prior to running a program that generates error messages, so we get English messages which are way easier to understand.

Comment: The problem is my min() function. Thanks for your help, now my program compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing one of the following:

1. Compilation of the file that contains the function definition, or
2. Missing to the link the file that contains compilation output (from
   the above step).

For a quick overview of compilation and linking process, see this https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html#zz-1.4